# after setting a member variable value the value is changing inside getter function

Tags: c++, floating-accuracy

I am trying to set two member variable which are **float** type and also succeed for one(which is nothing but directly assigned inside of a setter function). But another one need some calculation and with `static_cast<float>` I have configured it after calculation. For the second variable I have checked it inside of the setter function and found it is configured correctly but while I have tried to fetch it through `getter function` or directly by  `class object` it is showing some weird value.

source code:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class dosomething{
    public:
        float res_value_a;
        float res_value_b;

        void set_res_value_a ()
        {
            res_value_a = 0.35;
        }

        float get_res_value_a(){
            return res_value_a;
        }

        void set_res_value_b(int  set_value_b)
        {
            int b = pow (2, 6);
            float res_value_b = static_cast<float>(set_value_b)/b;
            cout<<"value of res_value_b after setting is: "<<res_value_b<<endl;
        }

        float get_res_value_b()
        {
            cout<<"value of res_value_b inside of getter function: "<<res_value_b<<endl;
            return res_value_b;
        }
};

int main()
{
    dosomething obj;
    obj.set_res_value_a();
    float ret_get_val_a = obj.get_res_value_a();
    cout<<"ret_get_val_a: "<<ret_get_val_a<<endl; // return value from function get_res_value_a
    cout<<"member variable res_value_a: "<<obj.res_value_a<<endl; // checking member variable value by object

    int  set_value_b;
    cin>> set_value_b;
    obj.set_res_value_b(set_value_b);
    float ret_get_val_b = obj.get_res_value_b();
    cout<<"ret_get_val_b: "<<ret_get_val_b<<endl; // return value from function get_res_value_b
    cout<<"member variable res_value_b: "<<obj.res_value_b<<endl; // checking member variable value by object

    return 0;
}
```

For `set_res_value_b` function I am also giving required input and expected output--

```
if set_value_b = 64 then res_value_b = 1
if set_value_b = 20 then res_value_b = 0.3125
if set_value_b = 134 then res_value_b = 2.09375
```

One error value I can give which got for `set_value_b = 20` and that is `res_value_b = 4.59149e-41`. What could be the cause for this error??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
            float res_value_b = static_cast<float>(set_value_b)/b;
```

is setting the value of not the member variable but a local variable.

Remove the first `float` to eliminate the local variable and have it set the member variable.

```
            res_value_b = static_cast<float>(set_value_b)/b;
```